# python requests module not able to upload file on django server

Tags: python, django, curl, libcurl, pycurl

I am trying to upload a file to django python server through python client.

I tried this -

```
import requests

url = 'http://wings.spectrumserver/sdm/lists'
files = {'file': open('file.ext', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

but somehow it is not working. `No error but no output/upload as well`

I am successfully upload files by browser and command line.

```
curl -i --form docfile=@localfilename http://wings.spectrumserver/sdm/lists
```

Please suggest what to do ??

I do not know much about curl and python but maybe someone could suggest something which is replica of this curl command in `pycurl` as it is already working with curl.

Please refer here for more details about question -

[upload file to django server using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848385/upload-file-to-django-server-using-curl)

Comment: I have the same problem. I look at the requests and there is nothing in there for request.FILES or request.POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is the name of file element. It should be `docfile`. In curl example you have passed that as `docfile` but in the python script you left it as `file`.

Alter this line:

```
files = {'file': open('file.ext', 'rb')}
```

to this:

```
files = {'docfile': open('file.ext', 'rb')}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the request in your view you may see it in request.FILES['file']
I had a problem because I was had a bad setting in a headers file.