# "CSRF token missing" when using curl with a Flask app

Tags: python, curl, flask

I am trying to submit a form on a Flask app using curl. Unfortunately, I keep running into the "CSRF token missing" error.

I tried:

`curl -X POST --form csrf_token=token --form data=@file.txt --form submit=submit {url} -v`

I used a `csrf_token` from the app while I had it open in a browser. I also looked at https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html and tried to set `X-CSRFToken` in the header but still got the same error. Any suggestions for what is the correct way to use curl to feed the token to the flask app?

Comment: yes, sorry that's what I meant. I will edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628275/how-to-use-curl-with-django-csrf-tokens-and-post-requests

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you just sending token and flask cannot get your session which lives in browser cookie. So if you wish to access your view via curl it's **not enough** to pass token value within POST request, **you have to attach cookie** to. You can write cookie to local  file with command:

```
curl -c /path/to/cookiefile {url}
```

Then modify it and send POST request to your server with attached cookie and token:

```
curl -b /path/to/cookiefile -X POST --form csrf_token=token --form data=@file.txt --form submit=submit {url} -v
```

Comment: Tried that also, without success.