# CSRF verification failed on post request to Django Server

Tags: json, django, rest, http

I'd like to post data to an endpoint hosted by Django. I am using cURL in my terminal to do this:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/bucket/create/ --data '{"name":"test2", "description":"hey"}'`

This returns the following error in an xml message:

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie
> when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons,
> to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
>
> If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please
> re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.
>
> Help Reason given for failure:
>
> ```
> CSRF cookie not set.
>  In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used
> ```
>
> correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
>
> Your browser is accepting cookies. The view function passes a request
> to the template’s render method. In the template, there is a {%
> csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an
> internal URL. If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must
> use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as
> well as those that accept the POST data. The form has a valid CSRF
> token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back
> button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form,
> because the token is rotated after a login.

I tried adding a `@csrf_exempt` decorator to the relevant backend view but this does not help. I'm not sure how to properly make API requests to my Django server.

Comment: check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628275/how-to-use-curl-with-django-csrf-tokens-and-post-requests

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django Version 4.0

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins

has to be included in the settings.

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.example.com']

add this to the settings.py